# CSS3 Slider does not work on my web

Tags: html, css, slider

im triying to implement this responsive CSS slider on my web:

```
http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi
```

I put all the code exactly as I saw in this example.

My code is this (from the principal section) in HTML:

```
      <section class="main-section">
      <div id="slider">
<figure>
Here are the 5 pictures but I cant put them becaouse I have less than 10 points of reputation. However, are the same links of codepen.
</figure>
</div>
  </section>
```

And in the CSS is this:

```
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
```

As you can see I put exactly the code, even the same pictures, but it does not work. If I make a new html and css, just with the div slider in the body, its works.

Main section is next to a nav tag, and before a footer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codepen is using prefixfree.min.js by default and it's not mentioned in the visible code boxes. The animations used in the CSS need prefixes to work in your browser.
You have 2 options:

1. Download [prefixfree.min.js](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) and add it to your html and it will automatically set CSS3 prefixes for the browser you are using.
2. Add the prefixes for each browser:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
div#slider {
    overflow: hidden;
}
div#slider figure img {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
div#slider figure {
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0;
  
    -webkit-animation: 30s slidy infinite;
    -moz-animation: 30s slidy infinite;
    -o-animation: 30s slidy infinite;
    animation: 30s slidy infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
    0% {left: 0%;}
    20% {left: 0%;}
    25% {left: -100%;}
    45% {left: -100%;}
    50% {left: -200%;}
    70% {left: -200%;}
    75% {left: -300%;}
    95% {left: -300%;}
    100% {left: -400%;}
}
@-moz-keyframes slidy {
    0% {left: 0%;}
    20% {left: 0%;}
    25% {left: -100%;}
    45% {left: -100%;}
    50% {left: -200%;}
    70% {left: -200%;}
    75% {left: -300%;}
    95% {left: -300%;}
    100% {left: -400%;}
}
@-o-keyframes slidy {
    0% {left: 0%;}
    20% {left: 0%;}
    25% {left: -100%;}
    45% {left: -100%;}
    50% {left: -200%;}
    70% {left: -200%;}
    75% {left: -300%;}
    95% {left: -300%;}
    100% {left: -400%;}
}
@keyframes slidy {
    0% {left: 0%;}
    20% {left: 0%;}
    25% {left: -100%;}
    45% {left: -100%;}
    50% {left: -200%;}
    70% {left: -200%;}
    75% {left: -300%;}
    95% {left: -300%;}
    100% {left: -400%;}
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/taj-mahal.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ibiza.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ankor-wat.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer worked for me but i cant vote because stackoverflow does not allow me yet :(

Comment: @LeonardoCavani Oh I see. For accepting an answer on Stackoverflow you don't need to vote, you need to click on the check button below the down vote arrow.